# HTML5 Fullscreen support for a specific webpage consisting only text

Tags: javascript, css, html, fullscreen

I am a new intern in an organization. My lead has assigned me with a task to add the full screen functionality to a specific webpage in our website. I have been provided with the whole source code of our website. I am newbie to HTML 5. However I did a bit of research on Internet and found out a bit of code for supporting this functionality.

Now, the biggest problem for me is how to integrate this code into our source code and where to integrate the code. I have got 3 files with me.

1.index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
 <title>HTML5 Fullscreen Live Demo</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Jake Rocheleau">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://images.templatemonster.com/images/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="icon" href="http://images.templatemonster.com/images/favicon.ico">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles.css">

  <script type="text/javascript"         
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullscreen.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="w">
  <h1>HTML5 Fullscreen Basic Demo</h1>

  <p><center><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="fullbtn" class="btn">View Fullscreen</a>
  </center>    </p>

<div class="onlyfull"><center><strong>Look a special image!
   </strong><br><br><img        src="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/robertburns11-hp.jpg"
  a    alt="magic image"></center></div>
  </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

2.jquery.fullscreen.js

```
  // These helper functions available only to our plugin scope.
  function supportFullScreen(){
    var doc = document.documentElement;

    return ('requestFullscreen' in doc) ||
            ('mozRequestFullScreen' in doc && document.mozFullScreenEnabled) ||
            ('webkitRequestFullScreen' in doc);
 } 

  function requestFullScreen(elem){
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        elem.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    }
  } 

  function fullScreenStatus(){
    return document.fullscreen ||
            document.mozFullScreen ||
            document.webkitIsFullScreen ||
            false;
}

 function cancelFullScreen(){
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    }
  }

   function onFullScreenEvent(callback){
    $(document).on("fullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange", function(){
        // The full screen status is automatically
        // passed to our callback as an argument.
        callback(fullScreenStatus());
    });
   }

   // Adding a new test to the jQuery support object
    $.support.fullscreen = supportFullScreen();

   // Creating the plugin
    $.fn.fullScreen = function(props){
    if(!$.support.fullscreen || this.length !== 1) {
        // The plugin can be called only
        // on one element at a time

        return this;
    }

    if(fullScreenStatus()){
        // if we are already in fullscreen, exit
        cancelFullScreen();
        return this;
    }

    // You can potentially pas two arguments a color
    // for the background and a callback function

    var options = $.extend({
        'background'      : '#111',
        'callback'        : $.noop( ),
        'fullscreenClass' : 'fullScreen'
    }, props),

    elem = this,

    // This temporary div is the element that is
    // actually going to be enlarged in full screen

    fs = $('<div>', {
        'css' : {
            'overflow-y' : 'auto',
            'background' : options.background,
            'width'      : '100%',
            'height'     : '100%'
        }
    })
        .insertBefore(elem)
        .append(elem);

    // You can use the .fullScreen class to
    // apply styling to your element
    elem.addClass( options.fullscreenClass );

    // Inserting our element in the temporary
    // div, after which we zoom it in fullscreen

    requestFullScreen(fs.get(0));

    fs.click(function(e){
        if(e.target == this){
            // If the black bar was clicked
            cancelFullScreen();
        }
    });

    elem.cancel = function(){
        cancelFullScreen();
        return elem;
    };

    onFullScreenEvent(function(fullScreen){
        if(!fullScreen){
            // We have exited full screen.
                // Detach event listener
                $(document).off( 'fullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange webkitfullscreenchange' );
            // Remove the class and destroy
            // the temporary div

            elem.removeClass( options.fullscreenClass ).insertBefore(fs);
            fs.remove();
        }

        // Calling the facultative user supplied callback
        if(options.callback) {
                        options.callback(fullScreen);
                    }
      });

      return elem;
    };

     $.fn.cancelFullScreen = function( ) {
        cancelFullScreen();

        return this;
        };
```

3.style.css

http://blog.templatemonster.com/2013/07/30/how-to-use-html5-fullscreen-mode/

downloaded the code from above link,

Can someone please tell me weather i am using the right code for the right functionality?
If so how to integrate it and make it run.

Regards,
Newbie

Comment: @Godisgood please find the code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2j7f4k4f/embedded/result/